# How to add images to scrollview in basic4android

Tags: scrollview, basic4android

I want to load some images in a `ScrollView` in basic4android. This happened only once.

My Code:

```
Activity.LoadLayout("main")
Dim b As Bitmap
    Dim iv As ImageView
For i=1 To 10
b.Initialize(File.DirAssets,"1.png")
iv.Initialize("")
iv.Bitmap = b
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(iv,30dip,30dip,212,64)
Next
```

instead of 10 image, only one image appears in my `ScrollView`.
I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: why no one answers my question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 10
    Dim iv As ImageView 'create an ImageView for each bitmap
    iv.Initialize("") 'not interested in any events so we pass empty string.
    Dim bd As BitmapDrawable
    bd.Initialize(Bitmaps.Get(i))
    iv.Background = bd 'set the background of the image view.
    'add the image view to the scroll bar internal panel.
    ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(iv, 5dip, 5dip + i * 200dip, ScrollView1.Width - 10dip, 190dip)
Next
```

Try the above code that "should" work, I am not near B4A to test it but all the code looks right on my example.

Answer (score 0):

always addview on  top 30dip

```
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(iv,30dip,30dip,212,64)
```

Change value

```
ScrollView1.Panel.AddView(<Image>,<Left>,<Top>,<H>,<W>)
```